# Public greetings to newly joined discord members

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to develop a bot in discord using discord.py which would send a channel message when a new member joins.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.get_channel(channel_id).send(f"welcome, {member}...")
```

But it is not bring implemented... How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, because you are using `await` on `get_channel`. and as you can see below you shouldn't

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    await channel.send(f'Hello there {member.mention}')
```

Comment: Still not displaying... I have Mee6 in my server... Can it be due to it that my bot can't display?

Answer (score 0):

Your bot may not have permission to speak/chat on the channel. If it can't go to settings(for the channel) add your bots role than do the permission but make sure your bot has send_messages, read message history, and read messages on

Comment: I have already made a new role named admin and have added my bot to the role with all permissions enabled... Will that work?

Comment: Yes admin can chat to any channel and see any channel @Harsh Sarkar